# PHP DOM function file_get_html call after Complete Page load

Tags: javascript, php, dom

We are trying to fetch url from `PHP DOM` but webapge that we try to fetch has functionality (change price after page load) so now we need that `PHP Dom` function `file_get_html` get HTML after this `onload` functionality of remote page has been completed.

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.pad15 h4 a') as $article) {
    echo $article->innertext.'<br>';
}
foreach($html->find('p.sprc span.fb') as $pr){
        echo $pr->innertext.'<br>';
    }
$html->clear();
    unset($html);
```

Comment: This is not possible with `PHP Dom` you'll need to use something like `PhantomJS` that allows running for JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I right undestend question you problem is get html after loading js. It's impossible. Becouse php open connection and get data at once

Answer (score 1):

answer about you question is "NO"

php can not receive javascript rendered result. javascript is running on browser side and it not possible with php.

alternative is to do task with

http://phantomjs.org/

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```